# I developed the recording using the JavaScript web audio API, but the sound quality is poor

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-recording

I have created an application that sings along in the app with the web audio API of JavaScript. This worked perfectly on iOS safari and Chrome, but the sound quality was poor on Android Chrome. To solve this, I tried changing the audio deviceId, but it still didn't work. Does someone have information that might help?

Doubt: After recording, I pass the file to the server and play it on another page. I am wondering if this is causing the problem.

This is my code

```
function captureUserMedia(mediaConstraints) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConstraints).then(onMediaSuccess)["catch"]();
}

function record() {
    if (getParameterByName("startSec").length !== 0) {
        masterSound.currentTime = getParameterByName("startSec");
    }
    masterSound.play();
    if (document.querySelectorAll(".record")[0].getAttribute("status") == "off") {
        document.querySelectorAll(".record")[0].setAttribute("status", "on");
        document.querySelectorAll(".record")[0].classList.add("stoped");
        var mediaConstraints;
        const devices = navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
        devices.then((value) => {
            // mediaConstraints = {
            //     audio: {
            //         deviceId: {
            //             exact: value[0].deviceId
            //         }
            //     },
            //     video: false
            // };
            mediaConstraints = {
                audio: true,
                video: false,
            };
            captureUserMedia(mediaConstraints, onMediaSuccess);
        });

    } else {
        document.querySelectorAll(".record")[0].setAttribute("status", "off");
        document.querySelectorAll(".record")[0].classList.remove("stoped");
        mediaRecorder.stream.stop();
        masterSound.pause();
    }
}

function onMediaSuccess(stream) {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.controls = true;
    audio.files = true;
    audio.muted = true;
    audio.srcObject = stream;
    audio.play();
    var audiosContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".audio_wrapper")[0];
    audiosContainer.appendChild(audio);
    audiosContainer.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
    mediaRecorder = new MediaStreamRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.mimeType = 'audio/wav';
    mediaRecorder.stream = stream;
    mediaRecorder.recorderType = MediaRecorderWrapper;
    mediaRecorder.audioChannels = 1;
    mediaRecorder.start();
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (blob) {
        audioFile = blob;
        var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        document.querySelectorAll(".append_audio")[0].setAttribute("src", blobURL);

        function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName) {
            theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
            theBlob.name = fileName;
            return theBlob;
        }

        submit();

        function submit() {
            var audioTest = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
            audioTest.play();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: please post your code? specifically around `getUserMedia`

Comment: I just added it. thank you before.

Comment: Maybe you are recording from the phone call mic and not the video mic?

Comment: @CherryDT 
Yes it is correct! Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Check the available devices returned by enumerateDevices

Comment: @CherryDT I have tested all the IDs of available audio devices, but they are all being recorded at phone call volume.

Comment: Maybe you can ask for video and then record the audio stream from that, but it will cause irritating permission requests about the camera...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When trying to build high-quality audio with [`getDisplayMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia), in the past I've passed in [`MediaStreamConstraints`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamConstraints) that remove some of the default processing on the input track:

```
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(
            { 
                video: true, 
                audio: 
                    { 
                        channels: 2, 
                        autoGainControl: false, 
                        echoCancellation: false, 
                        noiseSuppression: false 
                    }
                }
            );
```

I'm still learning WebRTC myself, so I'm not sure if these same properties can be passed when using `getUserMedia` and `MediaConstraints`, but I thought I'd share in case helpful. It sounds like this might also be about available devices. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! This completely solved the sound quality problem. However, there is a problem with the volume being reduced when recording without the earsets on. Do you know anything about this?

Comment: I'm glad that helped with the quality! Off the top of my head I'd imagine it'd have to do with maybe the microphone that records when there's no earsets (on the laptop) is not as strong as the one used through the earsets. I'm sorry I can't be of more help, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue where we were getting complaints about very low sound/gain  - barely hearable - with our HTML/JS recording client when running on Chrome on some Android devices.

Ended up buying an older Samsung phone (Galaxy A8) to easily replicate the issue.

The culprit was `echoCancellation` being set to `false`. With it disabled, we had a very low volume on the recorded audio. The solution was to set `echoCancellation` as `true`.

We ended up removing the constraint altogether and relied on each browser's defaults (`echoCancellation` is enabled by default on Chrome, Safari, Firefox).

Worth mentioning that `autoGainControl` and `noiseSuppression` inherit the value of `echoCancellation`, more exactly, if you only set `audio: {echoCancellation: true}`  the other 2 constraints will also be set as `true`.